# Join 2 lists using zip_longest but removing groups with None

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

How do I remove those groups which have None in them? Is there another alternative to zip_longest?

```
str1 = ['-', '+']
str2 = ['a','b','c']

list(itertools.zip_longest(str1, str2))
```

Output:

```
[('-','a'), ('+','b'), (None,'c')]
```

Expected output:

```
[[-a], [+b]]
```

Comment: Just use plain old `zip()`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip_longest()` is there as an alternative to the regular built-in `zip()`, which will truncate to the shortest list you give as an argument:

```
>>> str1 = ['-', '+']
>>> str2 = ['a','b','c']
>>> zipped = list(zip(str1, str2))
>>> print(zipped)
[('-', 'a'), ('+', 'b')]
>>> # the following more closely resembles your desired output
>>> condensed = [''.join(tup) for tup in zipped]
>>> print(condensed)
['-a', '+b']
```

Note that you can also give a keyword argument `fillvalue` to `itertools.zip_longest()` to make it fill with something besides `None`:

```
>>> zipped_long = list(itertools.zip_longest(str1, str2, fillvalue='~'))
>>> print(zipped_long)
[('-', 'a'), ('+', 'b'), ('~', 'c')]
```